# Create Div and insert Dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>

$('<p />', 
{
    'text': 'My Products'
}).appendTo('#one');
$('<li />').appendTo('#one');
```

How can I **dynamically** create `<div id="one">` and insert it before div "two"? Also how would i handle the rest of the code I wrote above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("<div id='one'></div>").insertBefore("#two");
```

and you can handle your code like below

```
$('<p >My Products</p>').appendTo('#one');
```

reference [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) and [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

Comment: earlier my div id=one has an external css applied to it (#one{ width:200px; position:fixed; float:left;}). Now that I create it dynamically, the CSS is not applied. How do I apply CSS to div id=one?

Comment: you make a class in this you set all css which you have apply on #one

then after my code write this line $("#one").addClass("your new class name");

Comment: I did this $('<li />').appendTo("<div id='one'></div>")               .insertBefore("#two"); Where to add CSS?

Comment: $("<div id='one'></div>").insertBefore("#two");
$('<li />').appendTo("#one");
then it will work

Comment: and you can add class
$("<div id='one'></div>").insertBefore("#two");
$('<li />').appendTo("#one");
$("#one").addClass("your new class name");

Comment: It's not working as you suggest. Also can't this be combined to one single line using chaining? I can't figure out how

Comment: wait i will make a fiddle for you

Comment: i think you cant add <li> directly it will be under in <ul> tag

Answer (score 0):

Use [.insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)

```
$('<div />', {
    'text': 'Test',
    id: 'one'
}).insertBefore( "#two" );
```

DEMO- [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7y7FL/)

---

Updated after OP updated question

DEMO- [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7y7FL/1)

```
$('<div />', {
    'text': 'Test',
    id: 'one'
}).insertBefore("#two");
$('<p />', {
    'text': 'My Products'
}).appendTo('#one');
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uHiXalI/2/edit)**

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

```
var $cont = $('#content'),
    $p = $('<p />', {
        'text': 'My Products'
    }),
    $div = $('<div />', {
      'id'   : 'one',
      'html' : $p
    }).appendTo( $cont );
```

---

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uHiXalI/3/edit)**

```
var ids   = ['one','two','three'],
    texts = ['My products', 'About', 'Contact'],
    $cont = $('#content');

for(var i=0; i<ids.length; i++){

    var $p = $('<p />', {
      'text': texts[i]
    }),
    $div = $('<div />', {
      'id'   : ids[i],
      'html' : $p
    }).appendTo( $cont );

}
```

---

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uHiXalI/5/edit)**

```
var $cont = $('#content'),
    obj = {
       'one'   : 'My products',
       'two'   : 'About',
       'three' : 'Contact'
    },
    HTML = '';


for(var key in obj){
  if( obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ){
    HTML += "<p id='"+ key +"'>"+ obj.key +"</p>";    
  } 
} 

$cont.append( HTML ); // append only once. Faster!
```

Comment: In your first demo, the dynamic div gets added 'after' the existing div.

Answer (score 0):

u can use .before or  .insertBefore

```
 $('selector').before('new content');
 $('new content').insertBefore('selector');
```